# I am trying to render an animation with a transparent background but it isn't working

Tags: rendering, transparency

I am trying to render an animation with a transparent background. I've changed it to RGBA and film - transparent but when it is rendered and I try to open it it either doesn't open (MOV file) or has a black background.

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Here he recommends File Format > Ffmpeg, Encoding > Container > QuickTime, Video > Video Codec > QT, have you tried? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4emIy6vevcI

Comment: Don’t add emotional stuff like “PLEASE HELP” when you are already on a help asking site. Of course we are going to try and help you. Doing that just makes us feel badly, and potentially manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, because most video codecs do not support transparency in a frame. To get transparency as an output, render as images, or use a video codec that does support transparency (if there is one).